# Finding matrix representation of an Ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a $2$-dimensional ellipsoid centered at $(1,2)$. The axes are parallel to $y=x$ and $y=-x$, and it passes through points $(-1,0)$, $(3,4)$,$(0,3)$,$(2,1)$.

I would like to find the symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix positive definite $Q$ s.t.

$$E(y,Q)=\{ x:(x-y)^TQ(x-y)\le1\}$$

where $y$ is the center.

Comment: You probably mean an ellipse ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a "two dimensional ellipsoid" is usually just called an ellipse. It's a curve lying in the $xy$ plane.

I think this problem is overconstrained. As the previous answer explained, you can use the four points to obtain four linear equations for the elements of $Q$. But $Q$ is symmetric, so it actually has only 3 independent entries.

And, on top of that, you're told the axis vectors of the ellipse. So, my view is that we're doubly overconstrained.

Another way to think about the problem ...
We know the center and axis directions of the ellipse. So there are only two degrees of freedom left -- the lengths of the major and minor axes, $a$ and $b$. We have 4 points that the ellipse is supposed to pass through, giving us four equations that $a$ and $b$ must satisfy. So, as I said before, the problem is over-constrained.

If you do the numerical work, you may find that there is a solution. But, if so, this is a lucky accident, it seems to me.

Comment: Agree, the system is actually overdetermined. Specially looking at the fact that the axis parallel information was never mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the data into the question and solve the linear equations formed by the constraints. $y_1 = 1, y_2 = 2$. Put the points one by one in place of $x$. This will give you four equations which you can solve for elements of Q.

$$ Q = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for example, $x=(-1,0)$ gives you\
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -2 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\ -2 
\end{pmatrix} = 1
$$

since points lying on the surface of elliposid will satisfy equality.

Comment: What does the axes being parallel to y=x and y=-x mean?

Comment: Presumably it means that the axes of symmetry of the eliipse are parallel to the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. In other words, the ellipse is rotated 45 degrees from the normal "standard" orientation.

Comment: after calculations $b=c=-3/16$ ($Q$is symmetric) but $a+d=5/8$. I guess a=d. But is this related to the info about axes?